# Remote server returned 404

Tags: c#, web-services, endpoint

**Code**

**Web.config**

```
<endpoint address="https://localhost/webapi/ProductData.svc/Secured"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProductData"
          contract="Client.IProductData" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProductDataSecured" />
<endpoint address="https://fow01003.fbce.local/webapi/ProductData.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProductData1"
          contract="Client.IProductData" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProductData" />
```

**Controller**

```
client = new ProductDataClient("BasicHttpBinding_IProductData"); //This Works
client.Test(); // This fails
```

**Error messages**

*Exception*: There was no endpoint listening at https://fow01003.fbce.local/webapi/ProductData.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

*InnerException*: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

**Problem**

As shown above, theres'no endpoint listening. However, when I go to https://fow01003.fbce.local/webapi/ProductData.svc it shows me that the service is running and I can check the wsdl which holds all information it should.

(PS. FOW01003.fbce.local = localhost).

What steps can I take to find what really is going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your service through code from another virtual machine, or from the same virtual machine as the service is hosted?

Comment: The same machine, The webapi is hosted via IIS and as far as I know everything works properly there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already turn on [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to get more detailed infos about the error?
Configure it at least for the service side (client side would be a good idea, too ;) and you'll probably get some hints on the 404.

Comment: There was no channel actively listening at 'https://fow01003.fbce.local/webapi/ProductData.svc/$metadata'  is all the input i'm getting from that. Doesn't help me much further...

Comment: Did you create the service reference at some point and may it be that the service changed meanwhile? Maybe the test-method changed somehow which causes the 404. Could you try to update the service reference on the client side?

Comment: I've updated the service everytime I made some changes, however I found out that one of the connections was missing from the web config file in a location where I didn't think it would search for it.